# Selecting more than one label with expression builder?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a layer with placenames and would like to show only a few lables like villages and not farmnames in areas where I have selcted all the Labels on the layer.

So after I have selected some labels I open the Layer properties and go to Lables-Rendering - Data defined - Show label.
The data definition description is:

```
Data defined override
Active: yes   (ctrl|right-click toggles)
Expected input:
bool [1=True|0=False]
Valid input types:
boolean, int, double, string
Current definition (expression):
"navneobjekttype" = 5103
```

What I need is to get more lables than the 5103. I also need 5101, 5107 and maybe others.
Is it possible to edit the expression to pick up **more fields**?

Under is a acreenshot of a layer with nameplaces. It shows some selected labels, but only the one with (translated->) nameobjecttype = 5103

So I need to show more labels than the "5103s" out of what is currently selected on the layer.

[image: selected layers with]

Comment: Could you please share some data, as well as some images? Currently I have no real idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. I will try to post some screenshots

Comment: I don't get how you select the labels. Usually you select features.

Comment: You can edit the expression by using the IN operator like so :  "navneobjekttype" IN (5103, 5101, 5107)  This is good only if you dont have to many value...

Comment: Thank for answearing on this Erik and J.R have beeen away so sorry for late response. So Erik. Yes. Its features I try to select and the show and hide.

Comment: ...What I try to do is show/display some features and hide others. I need to select all features in some areas and hide them because the map will difficult to read. In other areas i would like so show alle nameplaces. For example remove all farm names, but not village names in the valleys. In the mountain areas show all nameplaces. So first select. Then filter the selection. Then hide.